# vb.net how to load current month or any specific month from database

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm a newbie in database programming, so can I ask for tips or help in any way to load my database where I want to load database with current month or any specific month I want, and also will it run still if I have 2 or more "where" statement in my mysqlcommand? Any answers will be appreciated, thank you.

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString
     Try
         conn.Open()
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where checkdate = '" & DateTime.Now.Month & " and check_number = '" & Label1.Text & "", conn)
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read
             DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("check_corporate"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("check_group"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("status"))
         End While
         dr.Dispose()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     End Try
     conn.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: 1. You aren't asking about *loading* your database, you're asking about *reading from* your database. 2. You can't have more than one `WHERE` clause in your query, but you can have one or more criteria in the `WHERE` clause. 3. Search for use of `Using` statements in VB.NET for disposable objects such as `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`. 4. Search for using parameters in your queries.

Comment: You really don't have a question here. Try to clarify exactly what you want your code to do, identify and post what it is not doing, and include any error messages, if applicable.

Comment: This question is more about SQL  than vb.net.
BUT you need to read about parametrized queries, the way you're building yours is a SQL Injection candy

Comment: Anyway with my current code, it doesn't seem to display the data from database where date = current month records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MONTH](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_month.asp) function

```vb
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(
    " select * from tblchecklist " & 
    " where MONTH(checkdate) = " & DateTime.Now.Month & 
    " and check_number = '" & Label1.Text & "'", conn)
```

I'm only answering your question. But you should also

- Parameterize your query
- Run your query on a background thread, not the UI thread
- Dispose of your IDisposable objects
- Name your controls
- Not use `SELECT *`, rather select what you need explicitly

Comment: Sorry: answers that still allow for sql injection are an automatic downvote from me, even if they work.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn no worries

Comment: Your code perfectly works for me now. By the way, sorry for the noob question. Whats the difference between the background thread queries and UI thread queries. Been trying to start with database mysql, with nothing much of an idea about parametizing queries, and such ... A background information will do for me to startup or tips which would be better, providing a sample basic code is much appreciated.

Comment: @NnekLecxe It's interesting also that Label1.Text is already populated with a check number when Form2 loads. I have a feeling you're storing your program's state on the UI, and if so, that's also another issue - probably a larger one than everything else I've mentioned.

Comment: @NnekLecxe when you query the database synchronously, execution of your thread is halted until the query is completed. This is why you would use a background thread, one that is not the UI thread. When running on the UI, your forms will be halted. And this creates a sluggish application. There are a few ways to run the query on a different thread, such as `System.Threading.Thread` or `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`, and another way is to use `Async ... Await`

Answer (score 2):

This improves some things:

```vb
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString
    Try 
         'Do NOT try to re-use the same connection object throughout your app or form
         'Thanks to connection pooling, it really is better to create (and immediately dispose)
         ' a new object for every query
         Dim cn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here")

         'Do NOT use string concatenation to put values into an SQL query!
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where checkdate = @Month and checkNumber = @CheckNum", cn)

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", DateTime.Now.Month)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckNum", Label1.Text)

         cn.Open()
         'Rather than looping through results, you can often assign the query result object as a data source
         DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     ' Use a Finally (or Using) block to close/dispose your connection object
     Finally
         cn.Dispose()
     End Try
 End Sub
```

But it's still wrong. The `Month` property is just a single integer. It sounds like you want the query to show anything from the entire month.

In that case, the best option looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString
    Dim SQL As String = "
SELECT ID, check_corporate, check_date, check_num, check_name, check_memo,
    check_amount, check_group, date_deposit, date_release, status
FROM tblchecklist 
WHERE checkdate >= @MonthStart AND checkdate < DATE_ADD(@MonthStart, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND checkNumber = @CheckNum"

    Try 
         Dim cn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here")
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonthStart", New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1))
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckNum", Label1.Text)

         cn.Open()
         DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     Finally
         cn.Dispose()
     End Try
 End Sub
```

The big change here is computing the date range. This is **much better** than checking the month value for the column in each row, because you only need to do it **once** instead of for every value in the table, and because it can still work with indexes in the table.

---

I also wanted to directly address this:

> will it run still if I have 2 or more "where" statement in my mysqlcommand?

No. You only get one `WHERE` clause. But that clause can have any number of boolean conditions (predicates) connected via `AND` and `OR` operators, and you can use string concatenation to build up this clause dynamically, as long as any user-supplied text uses query parameters.

Comment: One more thing, what does the "new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1))" means? what does the "1" stands for? And also, what if I wanna load a month lets say January, February and so on. I can't seem to understand how to tweak on that part

Comment: Really appreciate your sample code, gives me an overview with parameters. Thank you so much

Comment: The `New DateTime()` expression is building a new value for the beginning of the month... the "Month Start". So we supply a year and month based on the current day, and then the `1` is what day to use.